# AWS lambda function location results in InvalidToken-Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I want to get the lambda function that I deployed on AWS.

I simply use

```
aws lambda get-function --function-name MY_FUNCTION_NAME > MY_FUNCTION_NAME.txt
```

and click the URL under Location in the "Code" section of the output.

```
"Code": {
        "RepositoryType": "S3",
        "Location": "THE_URL_OF_THE_ZIP_ARCHIVE"
    },
```

However, when I open the URL, I get an error

> InvalidToken
>
> > The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.

and

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

in the browser console.

Can somebody help me out with this? I simply want to download the archive that contains my function code and the corresponding yml-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue by downloading it via CLI instead of entering the URL directly in the browser:

```
wget -i <THE_URL_OF_THE_ZIP_ARCHIVE> -O lambda_function_xy.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you don't have access to the S3 bucket.

A possible solution is to first make sure you are logged in, and then enter the URL which will allow you to access it (if you actually have access to that bucket). You can confirm your access to that bucket by going to the S3 console and manually going to the path of the Lambda zip file.

Otherwise, if you don't have access to the bucket then you won't be able to access the file.

Comment: I've already though about this but I cannot find the bucket where the acual zip file is. How can I make sure, that my user can access it? I am currently logged in with root access rights.